# How to define a handler for http errors when loading view content using ngView in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to display an error message when a view fails to load by throwing an `HTTP` error.

I currently use

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() { ... });
```

in my controller to run code after the ngView has loaded.

Is there a counterpart to `$viewContentLoaded` like `$viewContentError` or `$viewContentLoadError`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the [$routeChangeError](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L477) event. This event will be emitted i.a. if the template can't be loaded.

Comment: Thanks - that works as expected! I already have used that event elsewhere, not sure why I didn't think of using it for failed view loading.

Comment: One issue I'm having is that the view is loaded -> 500 error -> $routeChangeError is called -> retry (click button) -> view ajax request is not made again (cached response?) and error event is not fired. I'll have a look at $routeCache and see if I have to invalidate it on error.

Comment: $templateCache rather - but it wasn't the route caching, I just had to set $location.path(...) back to the previous url.